# How to allow a plugin webAPI to override an existing webAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I have a Web API controller, say `EmployeeController`, which we register using Autofac. Now we create another controller with the same name and route, but with different functionality. When we try to register this new `EmployeeController` (i.e., Plugin) using *Autofac*, we would get an exception like

> multiple types were found that match the controller named `EmployeeController`.

My objective is to successfully inject the second controller and override the functionality of the first controller with it.

***Project A - > Core Project***

```
namespace Main.API
{
    public class EmployeeController : ApiController
    {
        // Some Logic
    }    
}
```

***Project B - > Plug-in Project***

Later consumer want to override employee controller with same controller name

```
namespace Plugin.API
{
    public class EmployeeController : ApiController
    {
        // Some Logic
    }    
}
```

**Autofac**

```
// assemblies contains Main.API.dll & Plugin.API.dll
builder.RegisterApiControllers(assemblies.ToArray()).InstancePerRequest();
```

Comment: I think you will ne a custom registration source for this to work. http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/registration-sources.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to implement what you want I would use [AOP concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) which will make it easier to implement and more powerful.

[*Castle DynamicProxy*](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/blob/master/docs/dynamicproxy.md) project provides AOP concept for .net and can be used by *Autofac* with the `Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy2` nuget package.

You will have only 1 `EmployeeController` in your main project

```
namespace Main.API
{
    public class EmployeeController : ApiController
    {
        public virtual String Get(Int32 id)
        {
           // Some Logic
        }
    }    
}
```

and various `IInterceptor` in your plugin projects :

```
namespace Plugin 
{
    public class XEmployeeeControllerInterceptor : IInterceptor
    {
        public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            if(!invocation.Method.Name == nameof(Core.APi.EmployeeController.Get))
            {
                return; 
            }
            invocation.Proceed(); 

            // alter return value 
            invocation.ReturnValue = invocation.ReturnValue + "-intercepted";
        }
    }
}
```

Then register things like this:

```
builder.RegisterApiControllers(assemblies.ToArray())
       .InstancePerRequest()
       .EnableClassInterceptors();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies.ToArray())
       .As<IInterceptor>();
```

See [Type Interceptors](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/interceptors.html) for more information

Comment: Firstly I say thanks to Cyril Durand. Let me know, if there are is any possibility just simply exclude type (EmployeeController) from Main.API dll while doing the RegisterApiControllers ?.
Before DI Registration I will check there is any same types available between Main and Plugin, If it is available I want exclude type from Main then automatically I can access same type from Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Using this following code snippet you can override the same name of plugin controller.

```
public class CustomHttpControllerSelector : DefaultHttpControllerSelector
    {
        private readonly HttpConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly Lazy<Dictionary<string, HttpControllerDescriptor>> _controllers;


    /// <summary>
    /// custom http controllerselector
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="config"></param>
    public CustomHttpControllerSelector(HttpConfiguration config) : base(config)
    {
        _configuration = config;
        _controllers = new Lazy<Dictionary<string, HttpControllerDescriptor>>(InitializeControllerDictionary);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// GetControllerMapping
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override IDictionary<string, HttpControllerDescriptor> GetControllerMapping()
    {
        return _controllers.Value;
    }

    private Dictionary<string, HttpControllerDescriptor> InitializeControllerDictionary()
    {
        var controllers = new Dictionary<string, HttpControllerDescriptor>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        IAssembliesResolver assembliesResolver = _configuration.Services.GetAssembliesResolver();
        IHttpControllerTypeResolver controllersResolver = _configuration.Services.GetHttpControllerTypeResolver();
        ICollection<Type> controllerTypes = controllersResolver.GetControllerTypes(assembliesResolver);

        foreach (Type t in controllerTypes)
        {
            var controllerName = t.Name.Remove(t.Name.Length - DefaultHttpControllerSelector.ControllerSuffix.Length);

            //Remove Core API Controller and add the Plugin API controller.
            if (controllers.Keys.Contains(controllerName) && t.Namespace.Contains("Plugin"))
            {
                controllers.Remove(controllerName);
            }
            if (!controllers.Keys.Contains(controllerName))
            {
                controllers[controllerName] = new HttpControllerDescriptor(_configuration, t.Nam`enter code here`e, t);
            }
        }
        return controllers;
    }
}
```